# Upgrade multiplier for clicker game such as Adventure Capitalist

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello community I am making a clicker game but I don't know how to do the upgrade multiplier button such as Adventure Capitalist, I have a single script attached to each GameObject, total of six objects with the same script attached, where I have the Text object which shows a double value which is an array with six indexes, the problem here is that I have the multiplier button object attached with another script, I should do something as static (singleton) because each script has many objects, I only need to access to a single text which is upgrade price displayer crop which is non-static. Pls help me.

This is the code for the multiplier button

```
public class MultiplyManager : MonoBehaviour {
public void multiply_Crop_PerOne()
{
    UpgradeButtonCrop.multiplier = 1;
}
public void multiply_Crop_PerTen()
{
    UpgradeButtonCrop.multiplier = 10;
}
public void multiply_Crop_PerHundred()
{
    UpgradeButtonCrop.multiplier = 50;
}}
```

And this is the code for the text UI which I am working, what I want to do is make the multiplier button multiply the cost of the upgrade and increase its level, for example if I have an upgrade which costs 1 gold, the multiplier per ten should make that upgrade cost for 10 and increase 10 levels.

```
public class UpgradeButtonCrop : MonoBehaviour{
public static int multiplier;
public Button upgradeButton_crop;
public TMP_Text level_displayer_crop;
public TMP_Text perSec_displayer_crop;
public TMP_Text upgrade_price_displayer_crop;
[HideInInspector]
public double startGoldByUpgrade_crop;
public double startCurrentCost_crop;
public double[] crop_upgrade_price_arr = new double[6];
public int[] level_crop_arr = new int[6];

public void First_Crop_Button()
    {
        purchaseUpgradeCrop(0);
    }
    public void Second_Crop_Button()
    {
        purchaseUpgradeCrop(1);
    }
    public void Third_Crop_Button()
    {
        purchaseUpgradeCrop(2);
    }
    public void Fourth_Crop_Button()
    {
        purchaseUpgradeCrop(3);
    }
    public void Fifth_Crop_Button()
    {
        purchaseUpgradeCrop(4);
    }
    public void Last_Crop_Button()
    {
        purchaseUpgradeCrop(5);
    }
    public void purchaseUpgradeCrop(int index)
    {
        if ((level_crop_arr[index] + multiplier) <= max_level)
        {
                if (DataController.Instance.gold >= crop_upgrade_price_arr[index] * multiplier)
                {
                updateUI_Crop(index);
                updateUpgrade_Crop();

    upgrade_price_displayer_crop.text =  LargeNumber.ToString(crop_upgrade_price_arr[index]).ToString();
                DataController.Instance.saveUpgradeButton_Crop(this);
                }
            }
        else
        {
            UpgradeMessageManager.instance.Start_coroutine_cant_upgrade();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, please note that the tag [tag:UnityScript] is ment for Unity's *depricated scripting language* called UnityScript, and not a general tag for scripting within Unity (as stated in the tag description). Please only add that tag if you are actually using the UnityScript language, Since this question is about C# I have removed the tag for you, this helps keep the questions on-topic and in-line with the tags :).

Comment: Hi Remy thank you I will be careful next time.

Comment: You never initialize the values in your arrays so they are all `0` ... so `crop_upgrade_price_arr[index] * multiplier` will probably always be `0` as well ... a bit unclear where exactly your question goes ...

Answer (score 0):

You can find components in the scene;

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html

So you could do something like this;

```cs
class UpgradeButtonCrop : Monobehaviour {
    MultiplyManager _manager;

    void Start()
    {
       // Find the manager and save a reference
       _manager = FindObjectsOfType<MultiplyManager>().First();
    }

}
```

and since you now have a reference to that manager you can do something with it.

Also see this tutorial;
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kd68uKt4jk

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, tried with tmp_upgrade_button_crop = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<UpgradeButtonCrop>(); for (int i = 0; i < crop_upgrade_price_arr.Length; i++)
        {
            upgrade_price_displayer_crop.text = LargeNumber.ToString(crop_upgrade_price_arr[i] * value).ToString();
        } works but doesn't update the value, still holds the value of the first value that had.

Comment: used it after deleting the array but throws Null Reference Exception